# Finding PDF of Z given X and Y

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

Let X be uniformly distributed on the unit interval [0,1]. Let $Y = 8X-4$. Let $Z = Y^3 - Y $. Find PDF of Y and Z.
So far I have calculated the PDF of Y but I cannot express Y in terms of Z. I am not able to simplify the cubic equation. Any help is appreciated.

Edit:
To find PDF of y, I have $Fy(y) = P(Y<y)
 = P(X<(y+4)/8) = Fx((y+4)/8)$. Since X is uniformly distributed, $Fx(x) = x$. Therefore, $Fy(y) = (y+4)/8$. And i can get the pdf by differentiating Fy. How do I do the same to find $Fz(Z)$?

Comment: Please show your work

Comment: To find PDF of y, i have Fy(y) = P(Y<y) = P(X<(y+4)/8) = Fx((y+4)/8. Since X is uniformly distributed, Fx(x) = x. Therefore, Fy(y) = (y+4)/8. And i can get the pdf by differentiating Fy @MathLover

Comment: Please edit the question with those details and not in the comments.

Comment: What's your point? @GwendolynAnderson

Comment: Isn't $p_X(x) = 1$ on the interval [0,1]? @GwendolynAnderson

Comment: Yes, absolutely, I wrote the entirely notation wrong.  $p_X(x) = 1.0$ on the interval [0,1] and 0 elsewhere.  So what values can Y take and with what probabilities?

Comment: Y can take values from [-4,4]  with $p_x(x ) = 1/8$ @GwendolynAnderson

Comment: Z can take values from [-68, 60] and $Z = 512x^3-768x^2+376x-68$. What now?

Comment: Here is a resource for the change of variables  https://online.stat.psu.edu/stat414/lesson/22/22.2

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/129530/discussion-between-saquib-khan-and-gwendolyn-anderson).

Comment: My problem is that X or Y cannot be expressed in terms of Z alone. So how do I even begin to find the pdf of Z? @Gwendolyn Anderson

Comment: If you look at $Z$, a cubic, you can see that values range from -60 to 60, but half of the distribution is between -6 and 6 (since half of Y's distribution is between -2 and 2).  Further $Z = Y^3 - Y$ can be written as $Z = Y(Y + 1) (Y - 1)$ the product of three uniform random variables on the ranges $[-4, 4], [-3, 5], [-5, 3]$.  The Moment Generating Function technique can be used, but note it's not as simple as with a sum of random variables.    The square instance has been covered on Stack Exchange.  A distribution could also be simulated.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2145234/moment-generating-function-of-the-product-of-two-i-i-d-uniform-random-variables